# How to solve - .css was blocked due to MIME type when building tailwind

Tags: css, npm, tailwind-css, web-development-server, npm-publish

[image]

I was building my tailwind css project with - npm run build. But then when I open builded index.html , css file wasn't loading.
This is showing .How can I fix this!

I dont know what to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file path is correct and the file exists, in NodeJS you need to specify a path for static files.

Comment: I've fixed this by adding on link- text.css